# condor_qsub strange behaviour in bash script

Tags: bash, parallel-processing, jobs, grid-computing, condor

I'm trying to write a bash script that checks what kind of grid engine is available in the workstation, and depending on that starts to submit jobs. All jobs are simple bash scripts and this bash script also tries to write `text.sh` scripts to a local directory and then it tries to submit those jobs. In case of condor I have a hard time making this to work and spent a huge amount of time figuring the issue out, without success. The problem is that when I try this, I get the error `condor_qsub '-n' unrecognized option`. While I have never assigned such an option to condor_qsub as you might see below.

```
for IMG in $IMAGESETVARIABLE
  do
#IMAGESETVARIABLE is a bunch of NIFTI images

  RIGID_IMAGESET="$RIGID_IMAGESET rigid_${IMG}"
#We can ignore this, an internal option for application 

  BASENAME=` echo ${IMG} | cut -d '.' -f 1 `
 #Defining codes to be inserted into job script file, the file that will finally submitted to grid engine

  exe=" ${ANTSPATH}ANTS $DIM -m MI[${TEMPLATE},${IMG},1,32] -o rigid_${IMG} -i 0 --use-Histogram-Matching --number-of-affine-iterations 10000x10000x10000x10000x10000 $RIGIDTYPE"
  exe2="${ANTSPATH}WarpImageMultiTransform $DIM ${IMG} rigid_${IMG} rigid_${BASENAME}Affine${afftype} -R ${TEMPLATE}"
  pexe=" $exe >> job_${count}_metriclog.txt "

  qscript="job_${count}_qsub.sh"

  echo "$SCRIPTPREPEND" > $qscript

  echo "$exe" >> $qscript

  echo "$exe2" >> $qscript

##SGE###
###$DOQSUB is an argument passed by user. It asks for the grid engine###
  if [ $DOQSUB -eq 1 ] ; then
    id=`qsub -cwd -S /bin/bash -N antsBuildTemplate_rigid -v ITK_GLOBAL_DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_THREADS=1,LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH,ANTSPATH=$ANTSPATH $QSUBOPTS $qscript | awk '{print $3}'`
    jobIDs="$jobIDs $id"
    sleep 0.5
##PBS##
elif [ $DOQSUB -eq 4 ]; then
    echo "cp -R /jobtmp/pbstmp.\$PBS_JOBID/* ${currentdir}" >> $qscript;
    id=`qsub -N antsrigid -v ITK_GLOBAL_DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_THREADS=1,LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH,ANTSPATH=$ANTSPATH $QSUBOPTS -q nopreempt -l nodes=1:ppn=1 -l walltime=4:00:00 $qscript | awk '{print $1}'`
    jobIDs="$jobIDs $id"
        sleep 0.5
##run jobs serially##
elif  [ $DOQSUB -eq 2 ] ; then
  # Send pexe and exe2 to same job file so that they execute in series
echo $pexe >> job${count}_r.sh
echo $exe2 >> job${count}_r.sh

##XGrid, Apple grid engine###

elif  [ $DOQSUB -eq 3 ] ; then
id=`xgrid $XGRIDOPTS -job submit /bin/bash $qscript | awk '{sub(/;/,"");print $3}' | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's:  *: :g'`
#echo "xgrid $XGRIDOPTS -job submit /bin/bash $qscript"
    jobIDs="$jobIDs $id"

    #####Suspicious problematic snippet begins, submit with condor_qsub#####

elif [ $DOQSUB -eq 5 ] ; then   
id=`condor_qsub -v ITK_GLOBAL_DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_THREADS=1,LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH,ANTSPATH=$ANTSPATH $qscript | awk '{print $1}'`      
jobIDs="$jobIDs $id"
    sleep 0.5

    ####Suspicious problematic snippet ends

  elif  [ $DOQSUB -eq 0 ] ; then
  # execute jobs in series
  $exe
  $exe2
  fi

  ((count++))
done
```

Please note the above snippet is just part of a big script, I have narrowed down the problem to the above section.

Comment: so what's the error message? Can you run it via bash -x your-script, what will you get?

Comment: thanks for your response. The script fails to successfully submit the job, apparently an extra '-n' is passed to condor_qsub and I get 'condor_qsub '-n' unrecognized option'. In fact this script works with SGE, PBS but not condor_q. I'm wondering where '-n' is coming from.